# Fermat point amidst polygonal obstacles

Tags: plane-geometry, computational-geometry

Consider $k$ distinct points in 2D-plane with $n$ convex polygonal obstacles. Is there a poly-time algorithm (poly in $k$ and the total number of obstacle vertices) to find a point outside of all obstacles such that its sum of distances from the given $k$ points is minimum? If not, is there an approximation algo?

Would also appreciate pointers to related problems of finding a point with min-max distance, and the case with non-convex polygonal obstacles.

Thanks.

Comment: It may help to look at the Euclidean single facility location (ESFL) problem, which is similar to your question but without obstacles. E.g., Xue, Guoliang, and Yinyu Ye. "An efficient algorithm for minimizing a sum of Euclidean norms with applications." *SIAM Journal on Optimization*, 7, no. 4 (1997): 1017-1036.

Comment: Thank you @JosephO'Rourke.